# when bottom navigation use but route are not earse and back back to back screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /PlayHistoryListScreen

[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /DashboardScreen

[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /PlayHistoryListScreen

[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /DashboardScreen

[GETX] CLOSE TO ROUTE /DashboardScreen

[GETX] CLOSE TO ROUTE /PlayHistoryListScreen

[GETX] CLOSE TO ROUTE /DashboardScreen

[GETX] CLOSE TO ROUTE /PlayHistoryListScreen

my problem is that when i use bottom naviagtion an press back button then go to dasboard but after i touch on dasboarad but but all route first clear and page will automativ navugation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:tracking/constants/color_constants.dart';
import 'package:tracking/controller/bottom_nav_bar_controller.dart';

import '../../controller/drawer_controller.dart';

class BottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  BottomNavBar({super.key});

  final BottomNavBarController controller = Get.put(BottomNavBarController(), permanent: true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        // Handle back button press here
        // if (controller.selectedIndex.value != 0) {
        //   controller.selectedIndex.value = 0;
        //   CustomDrawerController.to.onTileSelect(0); // Go to the home screen on back button press
        //   return false; // Prevent default back button behavior
        // }
        //
        // else{
        //
        // }
        return true;
         // Allow default back button behavior
      },
      child: Obx(
            () => BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.map_outlined),
              label: 'Play History',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.logout),
              label: 'Logout',
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: controller.selectedIndex.value,
          backgroundColor: primaryColor,
          selectedItemColor: white,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.white60,
          onTap: controller.onTap,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:tracking/controller/dashboard_controller.dart';
import 'package:tracking/controller/drawer_controller.dart';
import 'package:tracking/controller/login_controller.dart';

class BottomNavBarController extends GetxController {
  static BottomNavBarController get to => Get.find();

  RxInt selectedIndex = RxInt(0);

  onTap(int index) {
    selectedIndex.value = index;
    if (index == 0) {
      if (Get.currentRoute != 'DashBoardScreen') {
        CustomDrawerController.to.onTileSelect(0);
      }
      // print(Get.currentRoute);
    }
    if (index == 1) {
      // Get.to(()=>)
      CustomDrawerController.to.onTileSelect(2);
      // print(Get.currentRoute);
    }
    if (index == 2) {
      selectedIndex.value=0;
      CustomDrawerController.to.onTileSelect(0);
      DashboardController.to.cancelAnimation();
      LoginController.to.logout();
    }
  }
}
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:tracking/controller/bottom_nav_bar_controller.dart';
import 'package:tracking/controller/dashboard_controller.dart';
import 'package:tracking/controller/login_controller.dart';
import 'package:tracking/view/activity_report_screen.dart';
import 'package:tracking/view/dashboard_screen.dart';
import 'package:tracking/view/play_history_list_screen.dart';

import '../view/alerts_screen.dart';

class CustomDrawerController extends GetxController {

  static CustomDrawerController get to => Get.find();
  RxInt selectedIndex = RxInt(0);
  final LoginController loginController = LoginController.to;
  RxString version = RxString('');

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getVersion();
  }

  getVersion() async {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    version.value = packageInfo.version;
  }

  onTileSelect(int index) {
    if (index != selectedIndex.value) {
      selectedIndex.value = index;
      switch (index) {
        case 0:
          BottomNavBarController.to.selectedIndex.value = 0;
          Get.to(() => DashboardScreen());
          break;
        case 1:
        // BottomNavBarController.to.selectedIndex.value = 1;
          DashboardController.to.getVehicleDetails(true, true, false);
          Get.to(() => ActivityReportScreen());
          break;
        case 2:
          BottomNavBarController.to.selectedIndex.value = 1;
          DashboardController.to.getVehicleDetails(true, false, true);
          Get.to(() => PlayHistoryListScreen());
          break;
        case 3:
          if (loginController.currentUser.value != null) {
            Get.to(() => AlertsScreen(userId: loginController.currentUser.value!.id));
          } else {
            // Handle the case where currentUser is null (you can show an error message or take appropriate action)
          }
          break;
      }
    } else {
      Get.back();
    }
  }
}
i use back button on play histroy screen then go to dasboard and all route will clear but my problem is dedcribe in appear on code
```